# How to delete cordinates in list

Tags: python

I hava a field and points.

```
 field= [[1, 2, 4, 4],
        [4, 1, 4, 2],
        [2, 1, 4, 3],
        [2, 4, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]]

points=[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
```

I need help with deleting points from field:
When I delete point (0, 1) from field, I get result

```
field= [[1, 4, 4],
        [4, 1, 4, 2],
        [2, 1, 4, 3],
        [2, 4, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

When I delete point (1, 1) from field,I get result

```
     field=[[1, 4, 4],
            [4, 4, 2],
            [2, 1, 4, 3],
            [2, 4, 2, 3],
            [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

When I delete point (2, 1), I get finish result

```
field= [[1, 4, 4],    
        [4, 4, 2],    
        [2, 4, 3],    
        [2, 4, 2, 3],     
        [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

How to delete those points?

Comment: Where do you have a problem? What program code have you written so far?

Comment: Have you tried `del field[2][1]`?

Comment: `points = set(points)` and `field = [[num for y,num in enumerate(s) if (x,y) not in points] for s in field]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `del`:

```
pt = (0,1)
del fields[0][1]
```

Keep in mind, though, that you can delete the wrong items. Say your points are (0,0), (0,1) - this will delete the first and *third* elemends from the first field...

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) statement :

```
>>> for i,j in points:
...  del field[i][j]
... 
>>> field
[[1, 4, 4],
 [4, 4, 2], 
 [2, 4, 3], 
 [2, 4, 2, 3], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```